# Calculate difference in different columns between rows by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data on work stations were workers worked by day, and I need to find how many days a worker began working in the same station he left off the period day. Each observation is one work-day per worker.

```
 worker.id | start.station | end.station |  day
    1      |     234       |     342     |   2015-01-02
    1      |     342       |     425     |   2015-01-03
    1      |     235       |     621     |   2015-01-04
    2      |     155       |     732     |   2015-01-02
    2      |     318       |     632     |   2015-01-03
    2      |     632       |     422     |   2015-01-04
```

So the desired outcomes would be to generate a variable (same) that identifies days in which worker started at same work station as he left off previous day (with `NA` or `FALSE` in first observation for each worker).

```
 worker.id | start.station | end.station |  day         |  same
    1      |     234       |     342     |   2015-01-02 |  FALSE
    1      |     342       |     425     |   2015-01-03 |  TRUE
    1      |     235       |     621     |   2015-01-04 |  FALSE
    2      |     155       |     732     |   2015-01-02 |  FALSE
    2      |     318       |     632     |   2015-01-03 |  FALSE
    2      |     632       |     422     |   2015-01-04 |  TRUE
```

I think something using `dplyr` would work, but not sure what.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder which error message you've got. Your code is a huge mishmash of old syntax/different packages/base R/etc. Try `df %>% group_by(worker.id) %>% mutate(same = start.station == lag(end.station, default = 0))` instead

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks, I tried that, but I get "Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'

Comment: You probably have issues with your formats. What is the class of `df$start.station` ?

Comment: Numeric @DavidArenburg

Comment: Please share your `dput(df)`

Comment: Perhpas try  `df %>% group_by(worker.id) %>% mutate(same = start.station == lag(end.station, default = FALSE))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
worker.id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
start.station<-c(234,342,235,155,218,632)
end.station<-c(342,425,621,732,632,422)
end.station<-c(342,425,621,732,632,422)
day<-c("2015-01-02"," 2015-01-03"," 2015-01-04"," 2015-01-02"," 2015-01-03"," 2015-01-04")
df<-data.frame(worker.id, start.station ,end.station, day)

  worker.id start.station end.station         day
1         1           234         342  2015-01-02
2         1           342         425  2015-01-03
3         1           235         621  2015-01-04
4         2           155         732  2015-01-02
5         2           218         632  2015-01-03
6         2           632         422  2015-01-04

df$same<-ifelse(df$start.station!=lag(df$end.station) | 
             df$day=="2015-01-02", "FALSE","TRUE")

worker.id start.station end.station        day  same
1         1           234         342 2015-01-02 FALSE
2         1           342         425 2015-01-03  TRUE
3         1           235         621 2015-01-04 FALSE
4         2           155         732 2015-01-02 FALSE
5         2           218         632 2015-01-03 FALSE
6         2           632         422 2015-01-04  TRUE
```

Per suggestions in comments below if you want to group by worker ID but use ifelse (clunky):

```
df <-df %>%
  group_by(worker.id) %>%
  mutate(same=ifelse(start.station!=lag(end.station) & 
    start.station!=NA, "FALSE","TRUE")) %>% 
  mutate(same=ifelse(is.na(same), "FALSE","TRUE"))

as.data.frame(df)
  worker.id start.station end.station         day  same
1         1           234         342  2015-01-02 FALSE
2         1           342         425  2015-01-03  TRUE
3         1           235         621  2015-01-04 FALSE
4         2           155         732  2015-01-02 FALSE
5         2           218         632  2015-01-03 FALSE
6         2           632         422  2015-01-04  TRUE
```

Comment: This isn't by a `worker.id` and what on earth is `ifelse` here for?

Comment: Yes, it's true what @DavidArenburg points out. In this example it works because worker.id=2 starts at a station different than worker.id=1 ended, but that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Yeah, I approached it with ``ifelse`` bc I thought ``dplyr`` was giving the OP problems. Using: ``df %>% group_by(worker.id) %>% mutate(same = start.station == lag(end.station, default = 0))`` as @DavidArenburg suggests works just fine with the example code above.

Comment: The following can also work using ifelse (more clunky however). ``df <-df %>%group_by(worker.id) %>% mutate(same=ifelse(start.station!=lag(end.station) & start.station!=NA, "FALSE","TRUE")) %>% mutate(same=ifelse(is.na(same), "FALSE","TRUE"))``

Comment: @Agustín Indaco if this post answers your question consider accepting the answer.